# C++ Project where I am trying to associate student ID to grade and courses to make report

Tags: c++, list, header, subclass, composition

I am writing code for a major project and I am stuck. The project was supposed to ask the user to associate several courses to an existing student along with the grade obtained. The print out a detailed report based off the user entered information. Where I am stuck at is pretty vital, I was able to use classes to input all the user data: first name, last name etc. But when I try to add a grade for the course that I entered the program shuts down, thus I cannot move on from there. any help would be awesome!

Here is the file

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Student.h"
    using namespace std;

   void Student::AddCourse(string c,int grade){

    v.push_back(make_pair(c,grade));

    }


     vector<course>::iterator it;
     for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<"Course: "<<it->first<<" Grade: "<<it->second<<endl;;
    }

    }

    int main()
    {
      int N;
     int st_id;
     string first_name;
     string last_name;
     string degree;
     string city;
    string state;
    string address;
    cout<<"Enter Number of student you want to record: ";
    cin>>N;
    Student **st=new Student*[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    cout<<"Enter student's Id: ";
    cin>>st_id;

    cout<<"Enter student's First name: ";
    cin>>first_name;

    cout<<"Enter student's Last name: ";
    cin>>last_name;

     cout<<"Enter student's Degree Abbreviation: ";
     cin>>degree;

      cout<<"Enter student's Home City: ";
      cin>>city;

     cout<<"Enter student's Home State: (i.e Maryland): ";
     cin>>state;

     cout<<"Enter student's Address (i.e 3605-Edmondson-Ave): ";
    cin>>address;



     st[i]=new Student(st_id,first_name,last_name,degree,city,state,address);
     system("CLS");
     }

     string course;
     int grade;
     char choice;
     while(choice!='n')
     {
     cout<<"Insert Student id: ";
     cin>>st_id;

     cout<<"Insert course: ";
     cin>>course;

    cout<<"Insert course grade: ";
    cin>>grade;

    st[st_id]->AddCourse(course,grade);
    cout<<"Want to add another? y/n ";
    cin>>choice;
    system("CLS");

   }
   cout<<"Enter student id to show the report";
   cin>>st_id;
   st[st_id]->ShowReport();
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Please structure your code in readable form

Comment: I believe i edited it right.

Comment: figure out where the problem is and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try attaching a debugger. add breakpoint at 'st[st_id]->AddCourse(course,grade);' and step into code.. maybe the vector is never actually initialised, so there is no place to push back into.. or something

Comment: why do you have pointers to students and not students? Why dont you use `std::vector<Student>`? You also use it inside `Student`

Comment: char choice;
 while (choice != 'n')  just after declaring choice is used ..where is the initialization?

Comment: I just deleted the code that is not needed so that I can get better help.

Comment: ok for removing irrelevant code, but initalizing a variable that you use is not irrelevant, because it considerably changes the meaning of your code

Comment: Unrelated: Placing stuff outside of the [header guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) makes the header guards kind of useless. Putting `using namespace std;`in a header is generally frowned on.

Comment: Interestingly, I would expect the `operator>>` to be overloaded if the class performs the input.  I didn't see that in your `main` function.  Or an input method for your class.  By accessing the members directly in `main` you are violating the *data hiding* rules.

Answer (score 0):

st[st_id]->AddCourse(course,grade); is dangerous. Where you can have 30 
Students which can have ids like 100 or 1000.

Create another class for course and define an association between them. e.g. Student 1..* <----> 1..* Course.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some simplicity.
Create an input function for your `Student` class:

```
class Student
{
  int id;
  std::string name;
  // other data members
  public:
    void input_with_prompt();
};
void Student::input_with_prompt()
{
  std::cout << "Enter student ID: ";
  std::cin >> id;
  // etc.
}
```

Your `for` loop in `main` then looks like:

```
int record_quantity;
std::cout << "Enter number of students: ";
std::cin >> record_quantity;
Student * database = new Student[record_quantity];
for (int i = 0; i < record_quantity; ++i)
{
  Student s;
  s.input_with_prompt();
  // Append to database
  database[i] = s;
}
//...
delete [] database;
```